# MongoShell works fine even though mongod is not active

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

When I enter the command

```
systemctl status mongod
```

I get:

Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-09-25 11:11:54 CEST; 1min 5s ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Process: 11690 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=48)
Main PID: 11690 (code=exited, status=48)

However,

```
mongosh
```

works just fine. I can use the databases and the collections therein, perform administrative tasks, everything. Hence this is not really a question about a problem, more a curiosity what is going on.

I would expect that e.g.

```
show dbs
```

would render an error message, but as said, everything works fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`(code=exited, status=48)` indicates that the mongod service failed to start because there was already something listening on the configured IP:port.

That might be a previous startup attempt of this service, another mongod service, or a non-systemd-managed instance of mongod.

Check with the netstat or ss command to see what is listening on port 27017.

Comment: Thank you. netstat -ntpl shows the following PID/Program name on 127.0.0.1:27017-> 1176/mongod